# Simplify expression generated with sympy codegen

Tags: python, c, sympy

I am using `sympy.utilities.codegen`  to generate some C-code which I use for numerical computations. For example a generated C-function looks somehow like this:

```
double f(double x, double y, double z){
    return M_PI*sin(M_PI*x)*sin(M_PI*y) + sin(M_PI*y)*sin(M_PI*z);
}
```

So in general I have larger functions with more expressions, which is problematic for my numerical computations. Since I work with CUDA I have a reduced set of registers for my computations.  What I want to do is to split an expression into smaller ones and also do some substitutions such that expensive computations are calculated only once. Here is an example what the above code would look like.

```
double f(double x, double y, double z){
    double sinx = sin(M_PI*x);
    double siny = sin(M_PI*y);
    double sinz = sin(M_PI*z);
    double result;

    result  = M_PI*sinx*siny;
    result += siny*sinz;
    return result;
}
```

So obviously for this small functions this substitutions doesn't pay off but in general this is the only way to get things to work for me for larger functions. So my questions would be, are there any simple built in options to get this kind of behaviour? The most important part for me would be to split up the calculation into small steps. I guess the substitution could be done with some string replacement routines.

Answer (score 4):

You most probably want to perform [common subexpression elimination](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/rewriting.html#module-sympy.simplify.cse_main).
In your example `siny` is the only expression actually being reused:

```
>>> expr = pi*sin(pi*x)*sin(pi*y) + sin(pi*y)*sin(pi*z)
>>> print(cse(expr))
([(x0, sin(pi*y))], [pi*x0*sin(pi*x) + x0*sin(pi*z)])
```

Usually compilers should already do these transformations - at least if you ask it
to ignore the non-associativity of e.g. floating point multiplication (by passing e.g. `-ffast-math`). I don't have any experience with `nvcc` though.

If you run into limitations when working with codegen for generating CUDA code - please feel free to improve upon it at and send Pull Requests to the [SymPy project](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/). Be sure to have the latest master branch checked out though since Jim Crist is currently refactoring the code printers: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/7823

Comment: Thank you, so cse helps me to reduce subexpressions but how can I use this with codegen? i.e. if I use cse before codegen I have a lot of new variables, how can I define this variables inside the codegen function?

Comment: I've figured out how to combine cse with codegen https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258575/502144

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer of Bjoern Dahlgren, the code can be generated like this:

```py
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')
f = pi*sin(pi*x)*sin(pi*y) + sin(pi*y)*sin(pi*z)

substitutions, result_expr = cse(f)
input_arguments = [InputArgument(symbol) for symbol in [x, y, z]]
local_vars = [Result(var_expr, name=str(var), result_var=var) for var, var_expr in substitutions]

routine = Routine('f', [*input_arguments], [Result(result_expr[0])], local_vars, [])
code_gen = get_code_generator('C99', 'project')
[(c_name, c_code), _] = code_gen.write([routine], routine.name, header=False, empty=False)
print(c_code)
```

Generated code is below:

```c
#include "f.h"
#include <math.h>
double f(double x, double y, double z) {
   const double x0 = sin(M_PI*y);
   double f_result;
   f_result = M_PI*x0*sin(M_PI*x) + x0*sin(M_PI*z);
   return f_result;
}
```