# How to use common expression elimination together (CSE) with codegen

Tags: python, sympy, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to use sympy.utilities.codegen. I need compute a complicated function and its derivative. As a simplified example the function `f` is

```py
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
f = 1 / (x - y)
df = f.diff(x)
[(_, c_code), _] = codegen([('f', f), ('df', df)], 'C99', header=False, empty=False)
print(c_code)
```

This generates the following code:

```c
#include "f.h"
#include <math.h>
double f(double x, double y) {
   double f_result;
   f_result = 1.0/(x - y);
   return f_result;
}
double df(double x, double y) {
   double df_result;
   df_result = -1/pow(x - y, 2);
   return df_result;
}
```

Although C compiler might be able to eliminate common sub-expressions, I don't want to fully rely on this. Moreover, I doubt that the compiler can do that across different functions. Also, I want the generated code to be at least somewhat readable. So, I'm using common expression elimination

```py
substitutions, result = cse([f, df])
print(substitutions, result)
```

```
[(x0, x - y)] [1/x0, -1/x0**2]
```

But when I try to generate code for substitutions, I get function instead of variable for `x0` and can't use it for calculation of `f` and `df`

```
[(_, c_code), _] = codegen((str(substitutions[0][0]), substitutions[0][1]), 'C99', header=False, empty=False)
print(c_code)
```

```c
#include "x0.h"
#include <math.h>
double x0(double x, double y) {
   double x0_result;
   x0_result = x - y;
   return x0_result;
}
```

I've also tried to use `CodeBlock`

```py
f2 = Symbol('f')
code_block = CodeBlock(Assignment(*substitutions[0]), Assignment(f2, result[0]))
[(c_name, c_code), _] = codegen(('f', code_block), 'C99', header=False, empty=False)
```

But the resulting code is ill-formed:

```c
#include "f.h"
#include <math.h>
double f(double x, double y) {
   double f_result;
   f_result = x0 = x - y;
   f = 1.0/x0;
   return f_result;
}
```

There is the question [Common sub-expression elimination using sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442940/common-sub-expression-elimination-using-sympy), but it uses `sympy.printing`, which is lower level and doesn't fit me.

There is also relevant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323791/502144, but it doesn't show how to generate code from simplified expression.

**So, the question is:** how can I generate code using `sympy.utilities.codegen` after expression is simplified with `cse`? I want the code to look like this:

```c
#include <math.h>
void compute(double x, double y, double* f, double* df) {
    double x0 = x - y;
    *f = 1.0/x0;
    *df = -1/pow(x0, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the desired result by constructing `Routine` directly instead of using `codegen` wrapper function. The key part is using `local_vars` for substitutions

```py
substitutions, result_expr = cse([f, df])
result_names = ['f', 'df']
input_arguments = [InputArgument(symbol) for symbol in [x, y]]
output_arguments = [OutputArgument(Symbol(name), name, expr) for expr, name in zip(result_expr, result_names)]
local_vars = [Result(var_expr, name=str(var), result_var=var) for var, var_expr in substitutions]

routine = Routine('compute', [*input_arguments, *output_arguments], [], local_vars, [])
code_gen = get_code_generator('C99', 'project')
[(c_name, c_code), _] = code_gen.write([routine], routine.name, header=False, empty=False)
print(c_code)
```

```c
#include "compute.h"
#include <math.h>
void compute(double x, double y, double *f, double *df) {
   const double x0 = x - y;
   (*f) = 1.0/x0;
   (*df) = -1/pow(x0, 2);
}
```

Comment: There is a `cse=True` flag you can set with `codegen`.

Comment: @smichr Unfortunately I wasn't able to find this flag in function `codegen`. Can you show, where it is declared and in which version of sympy (I'm currently using 1.12)?

Comment: It is in the dev 1.13 version, e.g. `cgen = CCodeGen(project="test", cse=True)`